# Complex PHP Array Diffs

Tags: php, arrays

I have a rather convoluted issue here. It may be best to express abstractly, but I will include my best effort at providing a dataset.

The goal is to analyze customer retention. We have a weekly meal prep delivery service (should be subscription-based, but alas, it is not presently compulsory) and want to know when people are coming, going and staying.

Each week I extract the orders from Wordpress database (because I, unfortunately, do not have control of production website) and provide critical analysis.

Basically we want to know, of the people who ordered this week (156, for instance, this week), how many of them are new, how many returned from last week, how many returned from two weeks ago, how many returned from three weeks ago, how many returned from four weeks ago, and then how many returned from 5 or more weeks ago.

So I feed all the user id's into a PHP script and compare them against my records of previous weeks' purchases and come out with arrays like so:

```
$new=array ( 0 => '262', 1 => '3112', 2 => '3136', 3 => '3138', 4 => '3139', 5 => '3140', 6 => '3141', 7 => '3142', 8 => '3144', 9 => '3146', 10 => '3147', 11 => '3148', 12 => '3149', 13 => '3150', 14 => '3151', 15 => '3152', 16 => '3154', 17 => '3156', 18 => '3157', 19 => '3158', 20 => '3160', 21 => '3161', 22 => '3163', 23 => '3164', );

$reorders=array ( 0 => '11', 1 => '14', 2 => '60', 3 => '101', 4 => '111', 5 => '114', 6 => '158', 7 => '205', 8 => '219', 9 => '223', 10 => '249', 11 => '298', 12 => '328', 13 => '389', 14 => '407', 15 => '442', 16 => '447', 17 => '458', 18 => '486', 19 => '515', 20 => '519', 21 => '706', 22 => '712', 23 => '731', 24 => '810', 25 => '816', 26 => '843', 27 => '848', 28 => '903', 29 => '913', 30 => '918', 31 => '934', 32 => '937', 33 => '956', 34 => '988', 35 => '1043', 36 => '1043', 37 => '1064', 38 => '1066', 39 => '1091', 40 => '1105', 41 => '1106', 42 => '1158', 43 => '1159', 44 => '1164', 45 => '1180', 46 => '1195', 47 => '1233', 48 => '1237', 49 => '1251', 50 => '1271', 51 => '1310', 52 => '1321', 53 => '1322', 54 => '1344', 55 => '1353', 56 => '1380', 57 => '1382', 58 => '1423', 59 => '1443', 60 => '1447', 61 => '1448', 62 => '1460', 63 => '1463', 64 => '1478', 65 => '1489', 66 => '1491', 67 => '1498', 68 => '1502', 69 => '1506', 70 => '1507', 71 => '1509', 72 => '1740', 73 => '1837', 74 => '2034', 75 => '2105', 76 => '2110', 77 => '2556', 78 => '2632', 79 => '2643', 80 => '2651', 81 => '2923', 82 => '3022', 83 => '3066', 84 => '3114', 85 => '3121', 86 => '3123', 87 => '3124', 88 => '3126', 89 => '3130', 90 => '3132', 91 => '3134', );

$reorders2=array ( 0 => '14', 1 => '60', 2 => '92', 3 => '101', 4 => '111', 5 => '114', 6 => '158', 7 => '219', 8 => '249', 9 => '328', 10 => '389', 11 => '407', 12 => '442', 13 => '447', 14 => '458', 15 => '486', 16 => '487', 17 => '680', 18 => '706', 19 => '712', 20 => '731', 21 => '768', 22 => '776', 23 => '810', 24 => '816', 25 => '824', 26 => '843', 27 => '844', 28 => '848', 29 => '890', 30 => '903', 31 => '913', 32 => '917', 33 => '918', 34 => '937', 35 => '988', 36 => '1026', 37 => '1039', 38 => '1043', 39 => '1043', 40 => '1064', 41 => '1066', 42 => '1091', 43 => '1105', 44 => '1164', 45 => '1175', 46 => '1180', 47 => '1186', 48 => '1195', 49 => '1218', 50 => '1233', 51 => '1234', 52 => '1237', 53 => '1310', 54 => '1321', 55 => '1322', 56 => '1344', 57 => '1353', 58 => '1380', 59 => '1382', 60 => '1423', 61 => '1443', 62 => '1447', 63 => '1448', 64 => '1463', 65 => '1478', 66 => '1489', 67 => '1491', 68 => '1498', 69 => '1502', 70 => '1506', 71 => '1507', 72 => '1740', 73 => '2105', 74 => '2556', 75 => '2632', 76 => '2643', 77 => '2651', 78 => '2923', 79 => '3022', 80 => '3066', );

$reorders3=array ( 0 => '11', 1 => '14', 2 => '60', 3 => '92', 4 => '158', 5 => '219', 6 => '249', 7 => '273', 8 => '280', 9 => '328', 10 => '407', 11 => '442', 12 => '447', 13 => '458', 14 => '486', 15 => '487', 16 => '515', 17 => '680', 18 => '706', 19 => '712', 20 => '731', 21 => '768', 22 => '776', 23 => '790', 24 => '810', 25 => '816', 26 => '824', 27 => '843', 28 => '903', 29 => '913', 30 => '917', 31 => '918', 32 => '934', 33 => '1026', 34 => '1066', 35 => '1091', 36 => '1102', 37 => '1105', 38 => '1106', 39 => '1158', 40 => '1164', 41 => '1180', 42 => '1218', 43 => '1234', 44 => '1251', 45 => '1310', 46 => '1321', 47 => '1322', 48 => '1382', 49 => '1422', 50 => '1423', 51 => '1443', 52 => '1447', 53 => '1453', 54 => '1457', 55 => '1463', 56 => '1478', 57 => '1491', 58 => '1498', 59 => '1502', 60 => '1506', 61 => '1507', 62 => '1509', 63 => '1740', 64 => '1837', 65 => '2034', 66 => '2105', 67 => '2110', );

$reorders4=array ( 0 => '11', 1 => '14', 2 => '60', 3 => '72', 4 => '101', 5 => '111', 6 => '114', 7 => '205', 8 => '219', 9 => '249', 10 => '273', 11 => '280', 12 => '298', 13 => '407', 14 => '447', 15 => '458', 16 => '486', 17 => '487', 18 => '513', 19 => '515', 20 => '706', 21 => '712', 22 => '731', 23 => '768', 24 => '790', 25 => '805', 26 => '810', 27 => '824', 28 => '844', 29 => '903', 30 => '913', 31 => '917', 32 => '934', 33 => '937', 34 => '1026', 35 => '1064', 36 => '1066', 37 => '1083', 38 => '1091', 39 => '1102', 40 => '1105', 41 => '1180', 42 => '1195', 43 => '1218', 44 => '1237', 45 => '1271', 46 => '1277', 47 => '1321', 48 => '1322', 49 => '1344', 50 => '1353', 51 => '1380', 52 => '1382', 53 => '1387', 54 => '1410', 55 => '1422', 56 => '1423', 57 => '1443', 58 => '1447', 59 => '1448', 60 => '1453', 61 => '1460', 62 => '1463', 63 => '1478', 64 => '1489', 65 => '1498', 66 => '1502', 67 => '1506', 68 => '1507', );

$none=array ( 0 => '153', 1 => '262', 2 => '463', 3 => '566', 4 => '738', 5 => '791', 6 => '876', 7 => '900', 8 => '909', 9 => '922', 10 => '978', 11 => '1015', 12 => '3112', 13 => '3136', 14 => '3138', 15 => '3139', 16 => '3140', 17 => '3141', 18 => '3142', 19 => '3144', 20 => '3146', 21 => '3147', 22 => '3148', 23 => '3149', 24 => '3150', 25 => '3151', 26 => '3152', 27 => '3154', 28 => '3156', 29 => '3157', 30 => '3158', 31 => '3160', 32 => '3161', 33 => '3163', 34 => '3164', );
```

Where `$reorders` is the users who ordered last week, `$reorders2` users from 2 weeks ago, etc. `$none` is the users who ordered this week but have not ordered in the last 1-4 weeks, hence they ordered 5 or more weeks ago, because they are not in `$new`.

Needless to say, there is a great deal of repetition. So next I must differentiate those customers who not only ordered last week, but also two weeks ago, etc. There are quite a few permutations. I've consolidated as much as possible as such:

> [0] [1] [2] [1+2] [3] [2/3] [1+2+3] [4] [2/4] [3/4] [1+2+3+4] [5+]

In order to find orders that match each grouping, I take a variety of array_diffs and array_merges as shown below:

```
echo count($new)."\t".count(array_diff($reorders,$reorders2,$reorders3,$reorders4))."\t"; //new and 1
echo count(array_diff($reorders2,$reorders,$reorders3,$reorders4))."\t"; //2
echo count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders,$reorders2),$reorders3,$reorders4))."\t"; //1 & 2
echo count(array_diff($reorders3,$reorders,$reorders2,$reorders4))."\t"; //3
echo count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders,$reorders3),$reorders2,$reorders4))+count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders2,$reorders3),$reorders,$reorders4))."\t"; //2/3
echo count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders,$reorders2,$reorders3),$reorders4))."\t"; //1 & 2 & 3
echo count(array_diff($reorders4,$reorders2,$reorders3,$reorders))."\t"; //4
echo count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders4,$reorders2),$reorders,$reorders3))+count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders4,$reorders),$reorders2,$reorders3))."\t"; //2/4
echo count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders4,$reorders2,$reorders),$reorders3))+count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders4,$reorders,$reorders3),$reorders2))+count(array_diff(array_intersect($reorders4,$reorders2,$reorders3),$reorders))."\t"; //3/4
echo count(array_intersect($reorders,$reorders2,$reorders3,$reorders4))."\t"; //1 & 2 & 3 & 4
echo count(array_diff($none,$new))."\t"; //5+
```

Now, I did my best to ensure that no order could be excluded from these formulae, but, they are. This week the total I come out with is 150/156, last week 159/166, two weeks ago 156/161, three weeks ago 156/157. Several times I've been only 1 short, but the past three weeks' disparities has me worried that I may have a more critical logical flaw and I'm not entirely sure how to chase it down.

Edit: Datasource creation logic:

```
$custs=array ( 0 => '11', 1 => '14', 2 => '60', 3 => '72', 4 => '92', 5 => '101', 6 => '111', 7 => '114', 8 => '153', 9 => '158', 10 => '205', 11 => '219', 12 => '223', 13 => '249', 14 => '262', 15 => '273', 16 => '280', 17 => '298', 18 => '328', 19 => '389', 20 => '407', 21 => '442', 22 => '447', 23 => '458', 24 => '463', 25 => '486', 26 => '487', 27 => '513', 28 => '515', 29 => '519', 30 => '566', 31 => '680', 32 => '706', 33 => '712', 34 => '731', 35 => '738', 36 => '768', 37 => '776', 38 => '790', 39 => '791', 40 => '805', 41 => '810', 42 => '816', 43 => '824', 44 => '843', 45 => '844', 46 => '848', 47 => '876', 48 => '890', 49 => '900', 50 => '903', 51 => '909', 52 => '913', 53 => '917', 54 => '918', 55 => '922', 56 => '934', 57 => '937', 58 => '956', 59 => '978', 60 => '988', 61 => '1015', 62 => '1026', 63 => '1039', 64 => '1043', 65 => '1043', 66 => '1064', 67 => '1066', 68 => '1083', 69 => '1091', 70 => '1102', 71 => '1105', 72 => '1106', 73 => '1158', 74 => '1159', 75 => '1164', 76 => '1175', 77 => '1180', 78 => '1186', 79 => '1195', 80 => '1218', 81 => '1233', 82 => '1234', 83 => '1237', 84 => '1251', 85 => '1271', 86 => '1277', 87 => '1310', 88 => '1321', 89 => '1322', 90 => '1344', 91 => '1353', 92 => '1380', 93 => '1382', 94 => '1387', 95 => '1410', 96 => '1422', 97 => '1423', 98 => '1443', 99 => '1447', 100 => '1448', 101 => '1453', 102 => '1457', 103 => '1460', 104 => '1463', 105 => '1478', 106 => '1489', 107 => '1491', 108 => '1498', 109 => '1502', 110 => '1506', 111 => '1507', 112 => '1509', 113 => '1740', 114 => '1837', 115 => '2034', 116 => '2105', 117 => '2110', 118 => '2556', 119 => '2632', 120 => '2643', 121 => '2651', 122 => '2923', 123 => '3022', 124 => '3066', 125 => '3112', 126 => '3114', 127 => '3121', 128 => '3123', 129 => '3124', 130 => '3126', 131 => '3130', 132 => '3132', 133 => '3134', 134 => '3136', 135 => '3138', 136 => '3139', 137 => '3140', 138 => '3141', 139 => '3142', 140 => '3144', 141 => '3146', 142 => '3147', 143 => '3148', 144 => '3149', 145 => '3150', 146 => '3151', 147 => '3152', 148 => '3154', 149 => '3156', 150 => '3157', 151 => '3158', 152 => '3160', 153 => '3161', 154 => '3163', 155 => '3164'); //pulled from database
```

Iterate, and check for past orders of each week

```
unset($c);
foreach($custs as $c){

    $q="select id from fitaf_orders where uid=$c and `week`=";
    $reo=$dbh->query($q.($week-1))->fetch();
    if(!empty($reo))$reorders[]=$c;

    $reo2=$dbh->query($q.($week-2))->fetch();
    if(!empty($reo2))$reorders2[]=$c;

    $reo3=$dbh->query($q.($week-3))->fetch();
    if(!empty($reo3))$reorders3[]=$c;

    $reo4=$dbh->query($q.($week-4))->fetch();
    if(!empty($reo4))$reorders4[]=$c;

    if(empty($reo)&&empty($reo2)&&empty($reo3)&&empty($reo4))$none[]=$c;
}
```

Comment: No one asked that, that I can recall, because I had included explanations. Sorry they were missing this time. I revised.

Comment: The only recommendations I received on last posting were to 1) improve formatting, which I believe I have done and 2) extract data from the user perspective, rather than the week perspective, which I'm not entirely sure how to go about, and not sure if would improve/achieve

Comment: So is `new` all orders from this week, `reorders` all orders from last week, etc? After a quick check, there are 155 unique user ids, shouldn't be 156?

Comment: That's correct, just came to the same conclusion myself. Not sure where one could've fallen out, or where the other 5 have gone. I'll post my code where I generate the arrays, I suppose?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing a permutation? I'm not fully understanding what you're trying to accomplish with the groupings, but I've noticed that you have e.g. `2/3`, `2/4`, and even `1+2+3+4`, but not `2+3+4`.

Comment: Sorry, misread your comment, @msg, `$new` is customers who have never ordered before. `$custs`, just added to OP is the total, 156 customers who ordered this week

Comment: It's still not clear to me exactly what output you're trying to achieve? Do you want the number of people who've ordered in each of the last 4 weeks specifically, or just the number who ordered in 1,2,3 or 4 of the last 4 weeks? or??? Also I notice your `$custs` array has two values which are 1043. This accounts for the 155/156 discrepancy...

Comment: @B.Fleming, the point is to group customers and reduce some of the permutations, so to have `1+2+4`, `1+3+4`,`2+3+4`, is just too many categories, so I've rolled it up into `3/4` (3 out of 4 past weeks the customer has ordered). So that gives us the impression of people being very consistent, just not every week. Separated by those who are intermittent orders and only ordered in 2 of the past 4 weeks. Hopefully that makes some sense. If you look at the array_diffs towards the bottom of the OP, you can see for 3/4 I have the 3 qualifying categories I listed above.

Comment: @Nick, Brilliant! Some customers do make multiple distinct orders per week, and I did not factor this into my code. So that explains that disparity, but not the remaining 5 that are not meeting one of the other criteria. Hopefully my explanation to B.Fleming helps clear up your other confusion.

Comment: I was missing a permutation. Those that ordered 3 and 4 weeks ago were being excluded. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @macheteYeti glad you got it figured out.

Comment: I suspected that might've been the cause. Glad you managed to track it down! Please consider submitting your solution as an answer and accepting it so that the community as a whole can know that the question no longer needs an answer :)

Comment: If you don't want to post an answer, just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the permutation of people who have ordered 3 and 4 weeks ago.